# Convert unsigned short to char

Tags: c++, c, char

I know there's other posts like this but I think mine is different. I have a group of numbers I wish to display. However, it's saved as unsigned short. As it's given to me from a network buffer, all my data is unsigned short format. So for a serial number starting with "ABC-" the two unsigned shorts will be holding 0x4142 and 0x432D (Already in ASCII format). I need to convert those to type char to display using printf and %s, but for the rest of my system, they need to remain as an unsigned short. This is what I've tried so far, but the output is blank:

```
unsigned char * num[3];

num[0] = (unsigned char*)(SYSTEM_N >> 8);
num[1] = (unsigned char*)(SYSTEM_N & 0x00FF);
printf("System Number: %s \r\n", num);
```

Can anyone shed some light on this for me? Thanks!

Comment: And conversion to char* should be conversion to char

Comment: `unsigned char * num[3];` do you get what is type of `num` ?

Comment: Why not `printf("System Number: %c%c\n", SYSTEM_N >> 8, SYSTEM_N & 0x00FF);`?  Your *"I need to...[use] %s"* is just making it harder.

Comment: @TonyD I was using %s, the output for char string format. This example is the short version of what I have. There's actually about 50 of these to output.

Comment: "was using" - fair enough - but it still seems to me that `%c%c` saves you copying first to an `unsigned char` array each time, and works out better.  If I were you and doing 50, I'd use a macro ala `#define CC(N) N >> 8, N & 0xFF` to add the `printf` arguments....

Comment: @TonyD - got the answer - see below. I put an extra pointer where it didn't belong.

Comment: Yes I know... same thing someone else posted here as a comment more than 15 minutes ago, then deleted for some reason.  Still doesn't make it easier than `%c%c`, but suit yourself.

Comment: @TonyD - I need to convert it to char for something else too... not just this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant to write

```
unsigned char num[3];
```

as you have it, you declare an array holding three `char*` pointers.

Also don't forget to set the closing NUL character, before printing:

```
num[2] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 7):

There are several errors: 1) array is too short, 2) defining the array as an array of pointers and 3) not terminating the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    unsigned short system_m = 0x4142;
    unsigned short system_n = 0x432D;
    unsigned char num[5];

    num[0] = system_m >> 8;
    num[1] = system_m & 0xFF;
    num[2] = system_n >> 8;
    num[3] = system_n & 0xFF;
    num[4] = '\0';
    printf("System Number: %s \r\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT** alternatively if you don't want to keep the string, just display the information with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    unsigned short system_m = 0x4142;
    unsigned short system_n = 0x432D;
    printf("System Number: %c%c%c%c \r\n",
           system_m >> 8, system_m & 0xFF, system_n >> 8, system_n & 0xFF);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
System Number: ABC-
```

Answer (score 0):

A general solution might be something like this, assuming `ushort_arr` contains the `unsigned short`s in an array and `ushort_arr_size` indicates its size.

```
char *str = malloc(ushort_arr_size * 2 + 1); 
// check if str == NULL

int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ushort_arr_size; i++) {
    str[j++] = ushort_arr[i] >> 8;
    str[j++] = ushort_arr[i];
}
str[j] = '\0';

printf("string is: %s\n", str);

free(str);
```

Though perhaps this might be more effective without the memory management, if you only want to print it once:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < ushort_arr_size; i++) {
    putchar(ushort_arr[i] >> 8);
    putchar(ushort_arr[i] & 0xFF);
}
```